# JFreeChart - Timeseries and CandleStick on the same chart

Tags: java, overlay, jfreechart, candlestick-chart, timeserieschart

I'm trying to produce a single chart in JFreeChart that consists of an overlaid candlestick chart and Timeseries plot. (a little like this)

[image: [![candlestick trend overlay][1]][1] (source: [prices-oil.org](http://www.prices-oil.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/oil1stapril.jpg))]

I have tried creating the Candlestick chart and adding an additional XY series along with it's it renderer but this results in a runtime error of

`org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection cannot be cast to org.jfree.data.xy.OHLCDataset`

A snippet of my code is as follows

```
private XYPlot plot;
private XYSeriesCollection dataTrend;
private XYItemRenderer renderer;

public OhlcChart(BarCollection bars)
{
    
JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart("FX Trader Prototype", "Time", "Value", getDataset(bars), true);
plot = (XYPlot)jfreechart.getPlot();
plot.setDomainPannable(true);
    
    
NumberAxis numberAxis = (NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis();
numberAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    numberAxis.setAutoRangeStickyZero(false);
numberAxis.setUpperMargin(0.0D);
numberAxis.setLowerMargin(0.0D);
    
DateAxis dateAxis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm.ss");
    dateAxis.setDateFormatOverride(formatter);

    this.renderer = plot.getRenderer();
    Stroke myStroke = new BasicStroke((float) 1.0);

    this.renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    this.renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
    this.renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, myStroke);
    
}

public OhlcChart update(Timeseries<Double> ts)
{
    Stroke myStroke = new BasicStroke((float) 1.0);
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer timeSeriesRenderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    timeSeriesRenderer.setBaseShapesVisible(false);
    timeSeriesRenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
    timeSeriesRenderer.setSeriesStroke(0, myStroke);
            
    UiTimeseries series = new UiTimeseries(ts);
    dataTrend.addSeries(series);
    plot.setDataset(plot.getDatasetCount()+1, dataTrend);
    plot.setRenderer(plot.getDatasetCount()+1, timeSeriesRenderer);
    
    return this;
}
```

Any advice would be gratefully received

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible using JFreeChart, the key is to create an additional dataset and renderer

You will need to create a new `TimeSeriesCollection` to hold the data for the three additional series

```java
TimeSeriesCollection otherDataSet = new TimeSeriesCollection();
TimeSeries ts1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1");
otherDataSet.addSeries(ts1);
TimeSeries ts2 = new TimeSeries("Series 2");
otherDataSet.addSeries(ts2);
TimeSeries ts3 = new TimeSeries("Series 2");
otherDataSet.addSeries(ts3);
```

Then add the data to the `TimeSeries` as normal.

You will then need to add the `otherDataSet` to the `Plot` in `OhlcChart` map it to the same axis at the original plot (`mapDatasetToRangeAxis`) and provide a `Renderer`

```java
//Add the otherDataSet to the plot and map it to the same axis at the original plot 
int index = 1;
plot.setDataset(index, otherDataSet);
plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(index, 0);

XYItemRenderer renderer2 = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);
plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);
```

Here is an example using an `OHLCDataset` rather than a `BoxAndWhiskerXYDataset`

[image]